# Wordpress Sudden Loss of All CSS And Tons of JQuery Errors

Tags: css, jquery, wp-admin, scripts, admin-css

All of a sudden all the css on the wp-admin page of a Wordpress Site that I'm providing some maintenance for dropped out. It really came out of nowhere. I'm not sure what caused it. I took some pics of errors that appeared in the console.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is a pic of the source code for that first error "wp-admin:53:1"

[image]

The error is on a script tag so I'm assuming it's just not able to find something that it's importing... Idk... Does anyone know what's going on? Again this came out of nowhere. One day it was great now it won't work.

Comment: It seems like it could be a failed/incomplete update. Try manually updating WordPress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: When I click the raw html hyperlinked string that says update it just 404s on the mainpage but for some reason now I can see the toolbar. The consol says this "GEThttps://<Company Name>.com/wp-admin/update-core.php 404"

Comment: That’s why I said _manual_ update. Please read the link.

Comment: I tried replacing the files in "wp-includes" and "wp-admin" with the identical files of a working workpress install and it still gave the same errors. I even md5 hashes all the files in the directory of a working install and compared it with that of the broken install and basically all the relevant data was the same.

Comment: You should speak to your host. I notice your URLs are https, could your SSL certificate have expired? If you don’t know your host will be able to tell you.

Comment: I'd guess you've lost the .htaccess exception for serving files that exist on disk without routing them through WordPress somehow.

Comment: > > You should speak to your host. I notice your URLs are https, could your SSL certificate have expired?
  
Oh that's interesting, could an expired SSL Certificate cause this? It's not saying it's expired when I click on it in the browser

Comment: > > I'd guess you've lost the .htaccess exception for serving files that exist on disk without routing them through WordPress somehow.  
  
On further playing with the site, I went into the server and deleted all the htaccess files. I still have the same problem. The CSS and JQuery etc... won't load.